# Why does grep and grepl return different results in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

Forgive me if this is very obvious, I tried searching but couldn't find something specific to data frames on `grep`.

I was trying to search on two different columns, `geo` and `text`. I thought that `grep`, which returns row numbers, and `grepl`, which returns a logical vector, would return the same value for the test term "frank

```
> length(unique(temp[grepl("frank",temp[which(temp$geo=="New York"),"text"]),"text"]))
[1] 195
> length(unique(temp[grep("frank",temp[which(temp$geo=="New York"),"text"]),"text"]))
[1] 13
```

I tried filtering by `unique` thinking that I was getting duplicate rows, but it looks like this is not the case. I'm inclined to think that `grepl` is the correct function to use since `grepl` and `!grepl` return the complete search space, but I'm not sure. Interestingly returning the entire row gives me a different value for both.

Which one should I be using in order to get the correct results?

Comment: I think you are greping on a reduced `temp`. The resulting index of both grep and grepl didn't match that of full `temp` column. Try `length(unique(temp$text[grepl('framk', temp$text) & temp$geo == 'New York']))`

Comment: @mt1022 I'm sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: your grep/grepl index is relative to `temp[which(temp$geo=="New York"),"text"]` not `temp`. So both way are incorrect.

Comment: Correct, I was trying to search on two different columns. I believe that that is what that line is doing, but I'm not 100% sure. Did this somehow screw up grep? I assumed I was filtering twice. Looking on the results though, it looks like the test case `"frank"` is not in any of the results.

Comment: @mt1022 wait i see what you're saying, you're saying that I'm using two different indices. Crud. Is there any way to search two different columns this way?

Comment: you can put the two search condition together `grepl('frank', temp$text) & temp$geo == 'New York'`

Comment: @mt1022 Thank you for that, I was struggling with that bit. Why does `length(unique(temp[grepl('frank', temp$text) & which(temp$geo == 'New York'),"text"]))` return a different result? printing the result, they all look correct.

Comment: you are performing `&` operation between a logic vector derived from `grepl` and a numeric vector from `which`.  And the result of `which` would shorter than `nrow(temp)`. It will be OK if you remove the `which`.

Comment: @mt1022 I see that you are correct, using `which` was not returning what I was looking for. `grepl` and `==` both return a logical vector. How are these vectors compared to output the correct results from a data frame?